# Editing startup script from java

Tags: java, linux

I have startup script in my Linux machine  `/etc/init.d/myscr`. Need to add some lines in it from inside of java application.

I do very simple file write routines, but have exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \etc\init.d\myscr (No such file or directory)
```

Looks like java doesn't sees my file. Why?

Comment: What is Java running as, does it have permission to see and use the file? you may need to chmod it.

Comment: `\ ` != `/` - you're using the wrong path separator

Comment: It could be FilePath Issue or permission issue. Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `File.separator` when constructing the file path. Also make sure you have permission to write to the file.